# Error installing ruby-debug gem on osx yosemite

Tags: ruby, macos

Have anybody had success installing ruby-debug in osx yosmite ? I have ruby 2.2.1 and rvm 1.26.11 on my mac. However, when i tried to install ruby-debug, it fails with below error:

```
~ --> gem install ruby-debug
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/userid/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150812-26861-vlyh28.rb extconf.rb
Can't handle 1.9.x yet
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/userid/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/userid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/linecache-0.46 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/userid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/linecache-0.46/gem_make.out
~ -->
```

> ~ --> type rvm | head -1 rvm is a function  ~ --> rvm -v  rvm 1.26.11 
>   (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin , Michal Papis
>    [https://rvm.io/]   ~ --> ruby -v  ruby 2.2.1p85
>   (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]

Answer (score 1):

With that version of Ruby, you should use byebug instead of ruby-debug.

Comment: My initial intention was to debug the ruby code from eclipse ide. And eclipse complained about not having ruby-debug or debugger gem in the environment. I am not sure how to tell eclipse to use byebug instead of ruby-debug. Can you please help.